# Issue with mediaplayer and play songs in listview

Tags: android, listview, android-mediaplayer, media-player

I have a problem with playing songs, which are in listview.

Songs are correctly save, but I can not to play them.
I have a path of songs, so everything should work...
Here is a code in oncreate and outside:

```
    listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.filesList);
    ArrayList<String> FilesInFolder = GetFiles("/sdcard/Kandydaci");

    listView.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
            android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, FilesInFolder));

    listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View v, int position, long id) {
            MediaPlayer mediaPlayer = new MediaPlayer();
            try {
                File audioFile = getApplicationContext().getCacheDir();
                String name = (String) parent.getItemAtPosition(position);
                String OUTPUT_FILE ="sdcard/Kandydaci/"+name;
                mediaPlayer.setDataSource(OUTPUT_FILE);
                mediaPlayer.prepare();
                mediaPlayer.start();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    });

 public ArrayList<String> GetFiles(String DirectoryPath) {
    ArrayList<String> MyFiles = new ArrayList<String>();
    File f = new File(DirectoryPath);

    f.mkdirs();
    File[] files = f.listFiles();
    if (files.length == 0)
        return null;
    else {
        for (int i=0; i<files.length; i++)
            MyFiles.add(files[i].getName());
    }

    return MyFiles;
}
```

And here is bug, which I get after click on item in listview:

```
E/ExtMediaPlayer-JNI: env->IsInstanceOf fails
E/MediaPlayer-JNI: JNIMediaPlayerFactory: bIsQCMediaPlayerPresent 0
E/ExtMediaPlayer-JNI: env->IsInstanceOf fails
E/MediaPlayer-JNI: JNIMediaPlayerFactory: bIsQCMediaPlayerPresent 0
E/FileSource: Failed to open file 'sdcard/Kandydaci/Thu Nov 30 17:36:34 GMT+01:00 2017.mp3'. (Permission denied)
E/GenericSource: Failed to create data source!
E/MediaPlayer: error (1, -2147483648)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

your code is absolutely correct but problem is you missed defining permission to access EXTERNAL STORAGE.

So go like that.

**Declare in manifest:**

```
   <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
```

**Now add  this code before list setting:**

```
If(ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(MainActivity.this, permission) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) 
 { 
      // Should we show an explanation?
      if (ActivityCompat.shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale(MainActivity.this, permission)) 
      {
            //This is called if user has denied the permission before
            //In this case I am just asking the permission again 
           ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(MainActivity.this, new String[]{permission}, requestCode); 
     }
     else 
     { 
           ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(MainActivity.this, new String[]{permission}, requestCode);
     } 
 }
 else {
       Toast.makeText(this, "" + permission + " is already granted.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show(); 

  }
```

By this code you will get the storage access permissions, here permission is:

```
   String ="Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE";
```

Happy coding!!

Comment: Anytime @swydev it's my pleasure to help you. Keep enjoying and coding. Let me know if need more help.